# ATmega328P bootloader

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, datasheet, microchip, bootloader

I have read the complete datasheet of the ATmega328P but have a few confusions regarding the chip. In the datasheet in a section I have found that there is no specific bootloader section and also the ATmega328P doesn't support the read-while write. As shown below:

[image]

---

Although in another section I have found that the ATmega328P has a read-while write section and also a bootloader. I am not sure what does that mean. Does it actually have that or not?

Kindly help me in this clarification. The images from the datasheet are given below:

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: [ATmega328P](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: There is an error in the datasheet. Here https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf you will see that only ATmega48 does not support Read-While-Write. But in  ATmega88A/88PA/168A/168PA/328/328P the Boot Loader Support provides a real Read-While-Write Self-
Programming mechanism for downloading and uploading program code by the MCU itself.

Comment: Thanks I've found that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the datasheet given in the link. The correct datasheet is [given](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf), which states that only ATmega48 does not support Read-While-Write. But the ATmega88A/88PA/168A/168PA/328/328P Supports the Boot Loader and real Read-While-Write Self- Programming mechanism for downloading and uploading program code by the MCU itself.

Answer (score -1):

It does not have a bootoader. It can support a bootloader if you program a bootloader and set the fuse bits to boot from the bootloader.

I don't know why there are both it does and does not support read-while-write, but that is rather irrelevant, as surely your bootloader that writes the application program to flash will have to anyway mostly wait until write is finished to write more to flash.

Comment: Also what about the NRWW and RWW? Are they present or not, because these were seen very often in the datasheet but in the statement it tells that it isnt present and the flash is a single piece.